# How does [Authorize(Roles="Administrator")] work in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5 for my project and need to set role privilege. However I do not understand on how 
`[Authorize(Roles="Administrator")]` 
works.

In the above code what is (Roles)? How do i see if it is the administrator?

Comment: u can write your custome Authorize if u want

Comment: u can take a look at this class on msdn  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the ASP.NET Identity tutorial at http://www.asp.net/identity
That should help you.